# Java array , print what is stored in the array

Tags: java, arrays

How do I print what is stored in the array in an easy way. I have been staring at this for the past 3 hours!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class December2012 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = new int[100];
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sum <= 100 && i < array.length) {
            System.out.print("Write in the " + (i + 1) + "th number: ");
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
            sum += array[i];
            i++;

        }
        System.out.print("You added: ");
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");

        System.out.println("\nsum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop the array to print all values.

Comment: Tried that but since I already am using i to store the array and if I try printing with j it prints 0

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record you could also use the new `for-each loop`

```
    for(int no : array ) {
        System.out.println(no);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
for(int j= 0 ; j<array.length;j++) {
    System.out.println(array[j]);
}
```

or

```
for (int j: array) {
     System.out.println(j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
   System.out.println("Value "+i+"="+array[i]);
}
```

thats all my friend :)

Comment: Tried that but since I already am using i to store the array and if I try printing with j it prints 0

Comment: The code given above will always sum to zero, because you allocate the array, but you never put any values in it.